# "Contraction mapping principle"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Are there any applications of the following fact?:

Let $X$ be a complete Hausdorff semi-metric space with a collection of semi-metrics  $\{d_\alpha(\cdot,\cdot)\}_{\alpha\in A}.$
Further let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous mapping such that
for any $\alpha \in A$ there is a $\gamma \in A$ and a number $c > 0$ such that
$$d_\gamma(f(x),f(y))\le d_\gamma(x,y)-cd_\alpha(x,y),\quad \forall x,y\in X.$$
Then $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Comment: I have my doubts whether this question is off-topic: it does not ask about the standard contraction mapping principle but a generalization of it. It anything the question might have poor motivation, but it seems to be research level mathematics to me.

Comment: I'd say this is a typical case of a question that *may* have interesting answers. I would give  the OP the opportunity to improve the question before closing, and in any case I would  give an explanation for closing.

Comment: See Meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1142/12898

Comment: cuckoo: is there a source for this fact?

Comment: what if $d_\alpha(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: @Suvrit: I guess such $d_\alpha$ is  less interesting (the relation is trivially satisfied with $\gamma=\alpha$). But since $X$ is Hausdorff  by assumption, for any $x\neq y$ there is some $\alpha$ for which $d_\alpha(x,y)>0$.

Comment: I was thinking that this is related to Caristi's FP theorem, and then I found this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0615  --- I think the OP and the author of the arxiv preprint are the same, but this preprint should have been mentioned in the question I think...